# Filter result(s) in array of class (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

In `Class`

```
class Objects {

    var number: Int!
    var name: String!

    init(number: Int, name: String) {
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

In `viewController`

```
    var allObjects = [Objects]()
    var inSearchMode = false

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell


        if inSearchMode {

            let fill: Objects!
            fill = filteredObject[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(fill)

        } else {

            let fill: Objects!
            fill = allObjects[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(fill)

            return cell
        }

    }

    return UITableViewCell()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if inSearchMode {

            return filteredObject.count

        }

        return allObjects.count

        }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false
            tableView.reloadData()
            view.endEditing(true)

        } else {

            inSearchMode = true
            var lowerCase = Int(searchBar.text!)
            filteredObject = allObjects.filter({$0.number == lowerCase})
            tableView.reloadData()

            print(filteredObject)

        }

    }
```

I would like to have a search bar that filters and shows only one result that contains the number we are looking for. I thought about using `contains` and put the number we input from the search bar.

I manage to get one object into the `filteredObject`, but it won't show up in the `tableView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at this part of your code:

```
if inSearchMode {

    let fill: Objects!
    fill = filteredObject[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(fill)

} else {

    let fill: Objects!
    fill = allObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(fill)

    return cell
}
```

You did not return a cell when you are in search mode, that is why you do not see anything when searching.

Comment: This works perfectly! It is quite normal to miss this small details once a project gets bigger, thank you very much

Comment: As a safe habit to prevent this situation from occurring, I usually dequeue my cell in the first line and return it on the last so that regardless what mistake I made the cell will be return, maybe just with the wrong content if i messed up. If for any reason there is a need to return an empty cell I'd call return nil instead of doing nothing to make it clear that I am returning nothing

Answer (score 2):

I would use a computed property to drive the tableview; This property is either all the objects or the filtered object(s):

```
var allObjects = [Objects]()
var filteredObjects: [Objects]?

var objects: [Objects] = {
    return filteredObjects ?? allObjects
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.objects.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

    let fill = self.objects[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(fill)

    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        self.filteredObjects = nil
    } else {
        var lowerCase = Int(searchBar.text!)
        self.filteredObjects = allObjects.filter({$0.number == lowerCase})
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```